# error with JavaFX program

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx

I created a program in JavaFX and a register that has two date and time fields, which are filled at the time of registration. Using hibernate with annotations to do the mapping, it generates this error when I submit the date and time and will save:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

at br.upf.ads.daoo.global.action.AbstractAction.actionPerformed(AbstractAction.java:63)

at br.upf.ads.daoo.global.controller.AbstractController.handle(AbstractController.java:156)

at br.upf.ads.daoo.global.controller.AbstractController.handle(AbstractController.java:31)

at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)

at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)

at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)

at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)

at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)

at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)

at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6863)

at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)

at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)

at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)

at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)

at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)

at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)

at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)

at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)

at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)

at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)

at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)

at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)

at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3328)

at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3168)

at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3123)

at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)

at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2265)

at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)

at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)

at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)

at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)

at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)

at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)

at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

```
at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:615)

at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:272)

at br.upf.ads.daoo.ui.CompraIncluirView.loadCompraFromPanel(CompraIncluirView.java:179)

at br.upf.ads.daoo.ui.CompraIncluirView.getCompra(CompraIncluirView.java:205)

at br.upf.ads.daoo.controller.CompraIncluirController$4.conditional(CompraIncluirController.java:58)

at br.upf.ads.daoo.global.action.ConditionalAction.action(ConditionalAction.java:51)

at br.upf.ads.daoo.global.action.AbstractAction.actionPerformed(AbstractAction.java:58)

... 50 more
```

What could be the error? Below is some code that I think is the error:

```
private Compra loadCompraFromPanel() {
    Integer id = null;
    try {
        id = Integer.parseInt(tfId.getText());
    } catch (Exception nex) {
    }    
     Date data = null;
    if (!tfData.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
       data= new Date(tfData.getText());        
    }

     Float valor = null;
    try {
        valor = Float.parseFloat(tfValor.getText());
    } catch (Exception nex) {
    }

     Date horario = null;
    if (!tfHorario.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
        horario = new Date(tfHorario.getText());  
    }
    Passageiro passageiro = cbPassageiro.getValue();
    Capital capital = cbCapital.getValue();


    return new Compra(id, data, valor, horario, passageiro, capital);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an `IllegalArgumentException` because you are passing `tfData.getText()` (a string) as the constructor for `data` (which is a [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)):

```
data= new Date(tfData.getText());
```

The constructors for the class [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28%29) are:

```
Date()
Date(int year, int month, int date) //Deprecated
Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min) //Deprecated
Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min, int sec) //Deprecated
Date(long date)
Date(String s) //Deprecated
```

Appariently the `String` returned from `tfData.getText()` is not in a valid format for the `Date(String s)` *(deprecated)* constructor.

Comment: `java.util.Date` _does_ have a (deprecated) `Date(String s)` constructor which I suspect is throwing an exception because the string is not in a format it expects. The OP should use a `DateFormat` instead.

Comment: The `Date(String s)` constructor doesn't appear on the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29), which is odd since `Date(int year, int month, int day)` is deprecated and its still there

Comment: You're looking at `java.sql.Date`. The stacktrace in the OP is showing `java.util.Date`

Comment: So I have to change my constructor ?

Comment: [@Wagui](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2489842/wagui) No, you have to pass it a valid parameter. You should probably use `DateFormat` as [@damo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1671856/damo) suggested tho

Comment: Okay, If `data= new Date(tfData.getText());` returns a String, how can I convert to Date?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because the value being passed to `new Date(String s)` cannot be parsed (either  `tfData.getText()` or `tfHorario.getText()`). However, you should use a [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) instead of the deprecated `Date` constructor. For example:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date horario = null;
try {
  horario = df.parse(tfHorario.getText());
} catch (ParseException e) {
  // The user didn't provide a string in the correct format, show an error or something
}
```

See also: [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)